# Merge multiple files: 1st Column (same string), 2nd Column (unique values per file)

Tags: python, bash, awk, merge

I have multiple files (*.csv) that have a common column ("Common_Title") with corresponding values ("Value#") and I need to merge these into a summary file.

A difficult part is I need all values to get passed onto the summary file, but individual files sometimes lack a certain "Common_Title" and therefore need to put a "0000" in its "Value#" place.

This is 3 example files, all a bit different

```
# File1.csv

Common_Title,Value1
AAAAA,1111
BBBBB,1111
CCCCC,1111

# File2.csv

Common_Title,Value2
AAAAA,2222
BBBBB,2222
DDDDD,2222
EEEEE,2222

# File3.csv

Common_Title,Value3
AAAAA,3333
BBBBB,3333
CCCCC,3333
EEEEE,3333
```

which I'd like to merge into this summary file

```
# MergedFiles123.csv

Common_Title,Value1,Value2,Value3
AAAAA,1111,2222,3333
BBBBB,1111,2222,3333
CCCCC,1111,0000,3333
DDDDD,0000,2222,0000
EEEEE,0000,2222,3333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F, '!a[$1]++ { keys[++i] = $1 } !r[FILENAME]++ { ++argind } { b[$1, argind] = $2 } END { for (i = 1; i in keys; ++i) { k = keys[i]; t = k; for (j = 1; j <= argind; ++j) t = t FS (length(b[k, j]) ? b[k, j] : "0000"); print t } }' file1 file2 file3
```

Output:

```
Common_Title,Value1,Value2,Value3
AAAAA,1111,2222,3333
BBBBB,1111,2222,3333
CCCCC,1111,0000,3333
DDDDD,0000,2222,0000
EEEEE,0000,2222,3333
```

Comments:

- `!a[$1]++ { keys[++i] = $1 }` With the condition `!a[$1]++`, block (`{}`) could only evaluate when `$1` is first encountered. Inside the block, the key (`$1`) is added to the `keys` array once.
- `!r[FILENAME]++ { ++argind }` Increments the counter `argind` everytime a new file is encountered.
- `{ b[$1, argind] = $2 }` Stores the data with reference to `key` and the current file's index `argind`.
- `END { for (i = 1; i in keys; ++i) { k = keys[i]; t = k; for (j = 1; j <= argind; ++j) t = t FS (length(b[k, j]) ? b[k, j] : "0000"); print t } }'` Runs after all files are processed. It walks through every key in `keys` in order; and prints all data based from that key as a single line which is taken from `b[]` with included reference to the indices.

Comment: This merges all similar "Common_Title" but doesn't pass over the others which I still need. To make a complete summary, I'd like each 'Value#' column represented unique from others in the summary file. In my example I thought putting in "0000" where absent from a file might be useful.

Comment: To be clear, this is the output which is different than MergedFiles123.csv (above):                    Common_Title,Value1,Value2,Value3
AAAAA,1111,2222,3333
BBBBB,1111,2222,3333
CCCCC,1111,3333

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you, knsolebox!!  This is exactly what I need but I'll have to spend some time to understand this:         $ awk -F, '!a[$1]++ { keys[++i] = $1 } !r[FILENAME]++ { ++argind } { b[$1, argind] = $2 } END { for (i = 1; i in keys; ++i) { k = keys[i]; t = k; for (j = 1; j <= argind; ++j) t = t FS (length(b[k, j]) ? b[k, j] : "0000"); print t } }' File1.csv File2.csv File3.csv > MergedFiles123.csv

Comment: @BlacquenedRed You're welcome. I added some comments. I hope it can help you somehow. For anything, please refer to the GNU Awk's manual online. It's the most easiest manual of awk that you could refer to in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach but same output using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
}

FNR == 1 {
        filecount++
        numfields[filecount] = NF
        if (NR == 1) {
                a = split($0, header, FS)
        } else {
                for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
                        header[++a] = $i
                }
        }
}

FNR > 1 {
        for (j = 2; j <= NF; j++) {
                b[$1][filecount, j] = $j
        }
}

END {
        for (k = 1; k <= length(header); k++) {
                printf "%s%s", header[k], ((k < length(header)) ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        for (l in b) {
                printf "%s", l OFS
                for (m = 1; m <= filecount; m++) {
                        for (n = 2; n <= numfields[m]; n++) {
                                printf "%s%s",
                                (b[l][m, n] == "" ? "0000" : b[l][m, n]),
                                ((m + n < filecount + numfields[m]) ? OFS : ORS)
                        }
                }
        }
}' File*.csv
Common_Title,Value1,Value2,Value3
AAAAA,1111,2222,3333
BBBBB,1111,2222,3333
CCCCC,1111,0000,3333
DDDDD,0000,2222,0000
EEEEE,0000,2222,3333
```

---

This solution can handle a discordant number of fields between files, it fills missing values with "NA", and processes the header separately so the rest of the output can be sorted.

With different example data:

```
head file*
==> file1 <==
ID,Value
A1,10
A2,20
A3,30
A4,40

==> file2 <==
ID,Score,Extra
A2,200,True
A1,100,False

==> file3 <==
ID,Evaluation
A1,Correct
A3,Incorrect

==> file4 <==
ID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
A1,,1,1
A2,3,3,3,3

awk 'BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
}

FNR == 1 {
        filecount++
        numfields[filecount] = NF
        if (NR == 1) {
                a = split($0, header, FS)
        } else {
                for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
                        header[++a] = $i
                }
        }
}

FNR > 1 {
        for (j = 2; j <= NF; j++) {
                b[$1][filecount, j] = $j
        }
}

END {
        for (k = 1; k <= length(header); k++) {
                printf "%s%s", header[k], ((k < length(header)) ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        for (l in b) {
                printf "%s", l OFS
                for (m = 1; m <= filecount; m++) {
                        for (n = 2; n <= numfields[m]; n++) {
                                printf "%s%s",
                                (b[l][m, n] == "" ? "NA" : b[l][m, n]),
                                ((m + n < filecount + numfields[m]) ? OFS : ORS)
                        }
                }
        }
}' file*
ID,Value,Score,Extra,Evaluation,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
A1,10,100,False,Correct,NA,1,1,NA
A2,20,200,True,NA,3,3,3,3
A3,30,NA,NA,Incorrect,NA,NA,NA,NA
A4,40,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```